# Capture stdin input without echoing characters to screen

Tags: c++, qt, stdin

I have a very simple code:

```
char character;    
std::cin >> character;
```

However, I would like it to behave as follow:

1. Don't echo to console the character I type
2. `std::cin` should return (unblock) right away when a character is pressed without having to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

Is this possible? I also have access to Qt.

Comment: Redhat. Would like to know for Windows as well.

Comment: Are you trying to get characters or strings/lines?  getc() will snarf a single character.

Comment: I'm trying to get a single character.

Comment: +1.  Why the negative vote?  This is a valid question and asked reasonably well.

Comment: @Amardeep: A lot of angry programmers out there. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to be platform dependent, but you can use

`getch()` which is part of conio.h if you're on windows

or

`getch()` as part of curses.h if you're on *nix

References

- http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/curses.h.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: This answer is concise, and plain awesome.